# Disable button if only one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons. One where i clone a div (button-add) and one where I remove a div (button-remove).

I want to disable the remove-button when I only have one div.

So for multiple divs, it looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-add">+1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-remove">-1</button>
<div class="copybox"></div>
<div class="copybox"></div>
<div class="copybox"></div>
```

...and when there's only one div, I want it to look like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-remove" disabled>-1</button>
<div class="copybox"></div>
```

I use jQuery 1.11.3

Comment: `$("div.copybox").length` gives you the div count.

Comment: `$(".button-remove").prop("disabled", $("div.copybox").length<=1)`

Comment: @epascarello that one worked great. Only issue is that it's not updating when I click the add-button (so the disable function seems to only run once). I guess this has something to do with "on" (http://api.jquery.com/on/), but I can't seem to figure out how...

Comment: You should be calling that code when you click either button.

Comment: @epascarello hmm, it enables the "remove"-button after two clicks on the "add"-button, not one.

Comment: (other than that: it works as intended)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Hope this is what you need.

```js
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).text()=="+1")
  {
    $('.button-remove').prop('disabled',false);
    $('div.copybox:first').clone().appendTo('body');
  }
  else
  {
     $('div.copybox:last').remove();       
  }
  $('div.copybox').length==1?$(this).prop('disabled',true):$(this).prop('disabled',false)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-add">+1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-remove">-1</button>
<div class="copybox">Copy</div>
<div class="copybox">Copy</div>
<div class="copybox">Copy</div>
```

Comment: And how does it get enabled?

Comment: @epascarello.. Yep.. thanks for pointing out.. Added changes.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `$("div.copybox").length` that DontVoteMeDown commented and then set an ID for the button remove. Once you do that, you can add a function to hide the button with this code.

`document.getElementById(buttonID).style.display = 'none'`

If later you decide to enable it again, then you can also add another if statement and then the code for that would be `block` instead of `none`